# How to connect to a remote server(with password), ,switch user in remote system and then execute command and fetch output

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a command in remote system as a root user. Since remote root login is disabled, we need to connect as a admin user and switch to root and execute the command. how can we achieve this in python.

1. connect to remote system as a admin user.
2. switch to root user
3. execute commad as a root user(sudo permission not available)
4. disconnect from the remote system.

.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import time
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('x.x.x.x', port=22, username='admin', password='pass')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('su')
time.sleep(0.1) # some enviroment maybe need this.
stdin.write('root_password_goes_here\n')

#[ add extra code here to execute a command ]

stdin.flush()
print (stdout.readlines())
ssh.close()
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436013/ssh-login-as-user-and-change-to-root-without-sudo

i tried the above code but the command is always executed as a admin not as a root user.

Regards,
Ram

Comment: a quick google search would show that paramiko would be the way to go

Comment: i tried the above code which i have added, but the script is always executed as a admin user

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('su')
```

try ,

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/bin/su root -c "smartctl -a /dev/sda > /tmp/smartctl_output"', get_pty=True)
```

su allows to run commands with a substitute user and group ID. When called without arguments, su defaults to running an interactive shell as root.